# How to make abbrev ignore my custom keybindings?

Tags: key-bindings, abbreviations

For example, I've mapped `inoremap ( ()`, and if I do `iabbrev if if(then` it will expand to `if(then)` instead of `if()then` (the `inoremap` is executed after the `iabbrev`). Is it possible to make `iabbrev` ignore my custom keymappings so I can make `iabbrev if if()then` correctly expand to `if()then`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inoreabbrev` (insert-mode non-recursive abbreviation) is the command that will ignore custom mappings when executing the abbreviations.

To remove abbreviations without leaving vim use `iunabbrev [lhs]`. Now `inoreabbrev if if()then` should work correctly.

Comment: Thank you! It totally works. And also do you happen to know if there's any way to ignore custom mappings when editing macros (like `let @q = 'gg'`)?

Comment: `let @q = 'gg'` just sets the contents of the q-register, so it depends how you run the macro. I thought `:normal! @q` would work but apparently not, never tried it, so temporary fix could be `:normal! <C-r>q` to directly insert the contents of the q-register used for the macro and run ignoring remappings.